# I want to get image from JSON URL, but I got some error to get the Image In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, parsing

I want to get the images from JSON URL, so I need to use  JSON array and JSON object inside the list of images to display in Image View, but i got some error to get the JSON Array from JSON.

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "requestType": "bannerImages",
    "basePath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/",
    "bannerPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/",
    "response": {
        "data": [
            {
                "banner_id": "37",
                "banner_name": "1457324300894ac3df08bd3648452703d8412f82c2.jpg",
                "banner_link": "",
                "banner_blocked": "0",
                "banner_created": "admin",
                "created_on": "1457324300"
            },
            {
                "banner_id": "36",
                "banner_name": "14573242986be953c24858a3c2d787d57e6b77be1f.jpg",
                "banner_link": "",
                "banner_blocked": "0",
                "banner_created": "admin",
                "created_on": "1457324298"
            },
            {
                "banner_id": "35",
                "banner_name": "1457324295f8d8153fb4f29d3af15276db22435d48.jpg",
                "banner_link": "",
                "banner_blocked": "0",
                "banner_created": "admin",
                "created_on": "1457324295"
            }
        ]
    },
    "request": {
        "postData": [],
        "getData": {
            "type": "bannerImages",
            "result": "json"
        }
    }
}
```

CODE:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/qcrest1.0/?type=bannerImages&result=json"]


@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *bannerPath_NameArr,*finalout;
    NSString *jsonString;
    NSArray *array;
    NSString *arr1;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     statusarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });


   }
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.contentview;
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{

    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSMutableArray * outstatus = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(@"status %@", outstatus);
     jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\n" withString:@""];

    array = [[json objectForKey:@"response"]valueForKey:@"data"];

    NSString *arr3=[json objectForKey:@"bannerPath"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr3);

    NSString *arr2=[json objectForKey:@"basePath"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr2);

    [statusarray addObject:outstatus];
    [ban_path_arr addObject:arr3];
    [ban_base_arr addObject:arr2];

   NSDictionary *jsondic=[json valueForKeyPath:@"response.data"];
//    array = [[json objectForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"data"];
  NSArray *banname=[jsondic valueForKey:@"banner_name"];

    NSString *arr1=[json objectForKey:@"bannerPath"];
    array = [[json objectForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"data"];

//    for (int i=0; i<[banname count]; i++) {
//        NSArray *test=[banname objectAtIndex:i];
//        NSLog(@"%@",test);
//      imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",arr3,test];
//     NSLog(@"URL= %@",imageURL);
//    
//    }
    finalout=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [finalout addObject:imageURL];
    NSLog(@"array output %@",finalout);

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [finalout count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)

    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *UrlFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",arr1,[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"banner_name"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",UrlFormat);
    NSData *imageurl=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[finalout objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    cell.imgName.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageurl];

    return cell;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Log Error:

```
2016-05-05 17:40:21.578 pageview[2302:151094] status 200
2016-05-05 17:40:21.579 pageview[2302:151094] http://192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/banner/
2016-05-05 17:40:21.579 pageview[2302:151094] http://192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/
2016-05-05 17:40:21.597 pageview[2302:151094] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d9b1e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d42adeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8788c5 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 901
    3   pageview                            0x000000010cf168e0 -[ViewController fetchedData:] + 976
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010d013067 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 283
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8dda31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8d395c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8d2e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8d2828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    9   GraphicsServices                    0x00000001120b5ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010df86610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    11  pageview                            0x000000010cf1afdf main + 111
    12  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011031592d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I got error in for loop, I don't know how to convert JSON array by using for loop to get all the images in Image View.

How can I solve this problem. Very glad to apperciate.

Comment: change this line `NSArray* nsJson=  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondic
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` to `NSArray* nsJson=  [[json valueForKeyPath:@"response"] valueForKey:@"data"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you to get images

```
NSString *myImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: images];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell. imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
```

Comment: what the differernce between your code and questioner code

Comment: problem not in this code , problem in serlization , check once and modify your answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am using the same code to fetch images from json data

Comment: your code is fine bro, but problem not in here , the receving data bytes are missing

Answer (score 0):

use this code,

Declare the variable:

```
@interface ListViewController () {
    NSString *arr1;
}

@end
```

fetched Method:

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{

    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSMutableArray * outstatus = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(@"status %@", outstatus);

    arr1=[json objectForKey:@"bannerPath"];
    finalout = [[json objectForKey:@"response"]valueForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"print %@", finalout);
    // if you get the value its working fine.

    [tableviewname reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [finalout count];
}
```

if all the data values stored in array, then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)

    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

   NSString UrlFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",arr1,[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"banner_name"]];

    NSData *imageurl=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UrlFormat]];

    cell.imgName.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageurl];

    return cell;

}
```

change the above code in your source, please change the method **fetchedData** hope its helpful

Comment: I used your code, but I  got error object cannot be nill

Comment: Yes, I got error which JSON inside object it's showed error .

Comment: where is its, you could any link?

Comment: no I modified above asked question there u can check that

Comment: Your mistake is `finalout=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [finalout addObject:imageURL];
    NSLog(@"array output %@",finalout);` hide these lines, then change the array value **finalout** to **array** variable in all delegates

Comment: I already declared the finalout in an array, but i got a error object cannot be nil.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, If u know can u provide me code for that  because i tried almost in many ways for fetching the image.

Comment: simply change the above codes in your source code, you will change then run your source, put the breakpoint in **fetchedData:**  method, you can get the **finalout** array value or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "finalout" array its not contain proper data with index wise. Array not get data in proper format. You should use for loop and store one by one imageurl in "finalout" array.

Comment: please try this one  NSMutableArray * jsonarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        jsonarray = [oDict objectForKey:@"prod_info"];
    
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.count; i++)
            {
                [finalout addObject:[jsonarray objectAtIndex:i] Valueforkey@"bannerPath"]];
            }